# How to access Form.select values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this form where I want users to select how they want to post. Either with their name or anonymous.

So this is my form for that:

```
- @anonymous.each do |a|
 =form_for @confession , html: {multipart: true} do |f|
    =f.label :Confess
    =f.text_area :confession , require: true
    =f.label :post_as   
     =f.select(:postid,options_for_select([[@confession.amitian.fullname,@confession.amitian.fullname],[a.fullname,a.fullname]]))
    =f.file_field :confessionimage
    =f.submit 'Confess'
```

Now I have a user with option to select either their name or anonymous to post 
for that I have to build post with anonymous or current_user m confused how to do that in controller this is what I have done so far

```
def index 
  @amitian = Amitian.where(institute: current_amitian.institute) if     amitian_signed_in?
  @confessions = Confession.where(amitian_id: @amitian.ids).order('created_at DESC') if amitian_signed_in?
  @anonymous = Amitian.where(email: 'anonymous@anonymous.com')
  if #params[:postid] == 'Anonymous'  # i need an if statement to check what user has selected .. can anyone help plz ?
   @confession = @anonymous.confessions.build
  else
   @confession = current_amitian.confessions.build 
  end
end
```

thanx in advance

Comment: can you show us the params that come in from the logs?

Comment: params that [:postid] returns ?

Comment: the whole params, it's in your logs when you submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if your whole approach is right. I would add a boolean field to your Post (Confess?!) model. Like:

`rails g migration AddAnoncheckToConfess anonym:boolean`

Put that checkbox in your views and add it to your permitted params in your controller.

Then you could check in your index/show view if the user has set anonym to true:

```
<% if @confession.anonym == true %>
 Posted as anonymous
<% else %>
 <%= @confession.email %>
<% end %>
```

Cheers!